# Remove the last part of a string after underscore and random digit

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, strpos

My string looks like

```
$img_name = "my_beautiful_picture_123456_789101112131415_16171819202122.jpg"
```

What's the easiest way to remove from the first underscore followed by a digit to the end?

I would like to output

```
my_beautiful_picture
```

I tried

```
$img_name = substr($img_name, 0, strpos($img_name, "_"));
```

and

```
$img_name = preg_replace('/_[0-9].*/', '', $img_name);
```

But result is `my` for both, I'm not very familiar with regex.

Comment: I get the desired result with the `preg_replace()` method.

Comment: The second one works for me, and I don't see why it wouldn't work for you. If you've changed your code to that recently, I suspect caching, forgetting to save, loading the wrong file or some unrelated thing like that.

Comment: You would get `my` if the regexp were `/_.*/`,  but `[0-9]` ensures that there must be a digit after the underscore.

Comment: I haven't any cache. I just try on ideone.com and same result https://ideone.com/FRJqtw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could simply use a simple expression with `preg_replace` or `preg_match` or `preg_match_all`:

```
_[0-9].+
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/_[0-9].+/s';
$str = 'my_beautiful_picture_123456_789101112131415_16171819202122.jpg';
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### Output

```
my_beautiful_picture
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tCPf6t/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Hey @Emma, this is interesting, why do you think this worked when the `preg_replace` they previously tried didn't? I can't see why + instead of * would make a difference there. I must be missing something.

Comment: Actually, after I commented here I found a theory based on their ideone link under the question. I think I'll add an answer with my theory, mainly just because I'm curious if it is what I think it is. I'm not meaning to compete with your answer though, which seems perfect to me.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the code I saw in the ideone link you posted earlier, I have an idea what might have happened. If you tried it like this before:

```
echo $img_name2 = "my_beautiful_picture_123456_789101112131415_16171819202122.jpg";
echo " | ";
echo $img_name2 = substr($img_name2, 0, strpos($img_name2, "_"));
echo " | ";
echo $img_name2 = preg_replace('/_[0-9].*/', '', $img_name2);
```

The reason the `preg_replace` *looked like* it didn't work is that the previous `substr` had already reduced `$img_name2` to "my" before you used `preg_replace` on it. Since "my" doesn't have any underscores or numbers, that regex didn't match anything, so nothing was replaced and you just ended up with the same "my".

Comment: This is, of course, the real raison.@Rubyx: there're no needs to change `.*` to `.+`